# Java: Unwanted Row Separation with BufferedImage and 1D pixel array

Tags: java, arrays, image, bufferedimage, raycasting

Okay. So, I understand the code structure here and what should be happening, but no matter what I do, I can't get an image to render properly.

I'm following Sopiro's Classical 3D Rendering Tutorial #1, and I'm almost certain all of my code is exactly the same as his. However, after processing a random array of pixels with:

```
public void render(Bitmap b, int xOffset, int yOffset)
{
    for (int y=0; y<b.height; y++) 
    {
        int yPix = y + yOffset;
        for (int x=0; x<b.width; x++)
        {
            int xPix = x + xOffset;
            pixels[xPix + (yPix * width)] = b.pixels[x + (y * b.width)];
        }
    }
}
```

The `yOffset` and `xOffset` change the location of the image on the screen. The `pixels` array is the size of the window (ex. 640x480), whereas `b.pixels` is an array that represents the size of the image that is being added to `pixels`. So in effect, `b.pixels` is effectively added into the `pixels` array that represents the screen by simply changing the colors of pixels in a location determined by `yOffset` and `xOffset`.

I removed the bounds checking and will add that back in later. However, the pixels array is linked to an image with the following...

```
img = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    pixels = ((DataBufferInt)img.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
```

And drawn when needed with...

```
public void render()
{
    BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
    if (bs == null)
    {
        createBufferStrategy(3);
        return;
    }

    screen.render();

    for (int i=0; i<pixels.length; i++)
    {
        pixels[i] = screen.pixels[i];
    }

    Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE, null);
    g.dispose();
    bs.show();
}
```

Where `img` is the image represented by the `pixels` array.

This is what I get from this code:

[Faulty Program Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AwfT.png)
The rows should be touching each other, and not separated - I'm not sure if the error is in my code, or in the 'Black Box' pixels array -> image magic that is going on behind the scenes.

I would be happy to provide more code. Just let me know.

Thank you

Comment: What is `int xOffset` and `int yOffset`?

Comment: @DimaMaligin Those are just variables that change the location of the image on the screen. Actually, come to think of it, I'm going to add more of my own code to add context.

Comment: Cant say for sure but it might be that you need to `pixels[xPix + xOffset + (yPix * width + yOffset)] = b.pixels[x + (y * b.width)];` instead of "offsetting" before... but its realy hard to tell at this point.